# Route CakePHP Plugin from /users/users/index to /users/index

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3, routes

I have just dropped the CakeDC Users plugin into my CakePHP App, the only issue is that all the pages that use the plugin are accessed through `/users/users/action`, which looks rubbish with 'users' in there twice. It is my understanding that prior to CakePHP 1.3, there was 'magic' routing that put the users plugin in `/users`, is there a way to replicate this behaviour in CakePHP 1.3 ? I need it to work fine with admin prefixes too.

**Update**
After talking to the helpful guys in #cakephp, it's been suggested that I just setup 2 routes for the users plugin for the admin and 'normal' actions. There is noy way to re-create the 'magic' routing from 1.2.

```
Router::connect('/users/:action', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/admin/users/:action', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'prefix' => 'admin'));
```

Comment: You can change the route in cakePHP http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration

Comment: It only tells you have to create links to plugins, not route them. I tried /user/:action but ran into problems with the index action and logging in with Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just go to /users by default and you will get there.

cake will know automatically if the plugin is called users, and it has a controller called users with an action called index.